# Using pandas to group then graph mean log returns by day of the month for several years

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm trying to group mean log-returns by day of the month over the last few years then bucket and graph them as a bar chart. Here I use the resample function by passing "D" as the offset, but it doesn't group the data by days of the month. Also, when I pass "on='timestamp" into resample it yeilds a "Grouper name timestamp not found". (Side note, any resources for this type of data analysis would be welcome! I have Python for data analysis by Wes Mnkinney)

This is what i'm attempting to do (using pivot chart in excel):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqLtZ.png)

```
name = ['timestamp','open','high','low','close','volume']
df = pd.read_csv("daily_TLT.csv", parse_dates=['timestamp'])

df['log returns'] = (np.log(df.close) - np.log(df.close.shift(-1)))
df['day'] = df.timestamp.dt.day
df['year'] = df.timestamp.dt.year

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dat = [df['timestamp'], df['log returns']]
heads = ["timestamp", "logReturns"]
daily_data = pd.concat(dat, axis=1, keys=heads)
daily_data.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)

daily_data.resample('D').mean()

timestamp   open    high    low close   volume  log returns day year
0   2022-04-18  120.87  121.08  119.70  120.15  18778491    -0.004981   18  2022
1   2022-04-14  122.86  122.93  120.38  120.75  34274530    -0.020249   14  2022
2   2022-04-13  123.05  124.30  122.89  123.22  17189500    0.002031    13  2022
3   2022-04-12  124.05  124.16  122.67  122.97  23124178    -0.001381   12  2022
4   2022-04-11  123.92  124.19  122.56  123.14  30020696    -0.015951   11  2022
```

Result: Which has 1700 columns

```
          logReturns
timestamp   
2002-07-26  NaN
2002-07-27  NaN
2002-07-28  NaN
2002-07-29  -0.013299
2002-07-30  0.001227
```

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution, just getting familiar with the df.groupby function

```
name = ['timestamp','open','high','low','close','volume']
df = pd.read_csv("daily_TLT.csv", parse_dates=['timestamp'])
df.set_index(df['timestamp'], inplace=True)

df['log returns'] = (np.log(df.close) - np.log(df.close.shift(-1)))
df['day'] = df.timestamp.dt.day
df['year'] = df.timestamp.dt.year

series = df.groupby('day')['log returns'].mean()
series.plot(kind='bar',color='b')
plt.title("Mean Loggy Returns by Calendar DOM")
```